# Proteins that give color (without fluorescence)

Tags: biochemistry, proteins, biophysics

Are there **proteins** that have strong color, that could be seen without the need of UV and with naked eyes (with white light) - in mammalian cells?

Searching for reporter, something like GFP, but that we could see it without UV (not fluorescence).

Like chromoprotein - but it is problematic in mammalian cells because most chromoproteins need a prosthetic group.

Comment: You've read the [wikipedia page](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromoprotein) I assume? It has some examples.

Comment: Yes. I searching for something that may be used like GFP (reporter), but that we could see it without fluorescence and it's not chromoprotein - because like I mention it not perfect in mammalian cells, as far as I know.

Comment: The problem with these chromoproteins is that the color comes from a prosthetic group that is added to the protein later. If the cells can't produce the prosthetic group, or can't attach it to the protein, it won't be colored. I know you're not looking for fluorescent proteins, but I have seen E. coli express Red Fluorescent Protein and make reddish colonies, clearly visible on an agar gel. I can't say if mammalian cells would also make visibly red colonies.

Comment: I think it would help to add a cell type (e.g., red blood cells have red hemoglobin) or tissue (e.g. pigment epithelium in the retina is colored). As of now this question is quite brood as there are many colored proteins.

Comment: @AliceD Something universal - I wrote, like GFP.

Comment: with universal you mean occurring in *any* cell?

Comment: >"E. coli express Red Fluorescent Protein and make reddish colonies" Because they absorb almost all light from daylight (~white) spectrum

Comment: @aandreev Yes, the colonies that had the RFP gene were reddish under visible light, the colonies without the gene were normal E coli color. Made it easy to pick the transformed colonies off the plate. When using GFP, we had to put the plate on a UV light to see the green.

Comment: @VGranin I think we should clarify what you want to do with this reporter. Do you want to see color with the naked eye? Are you looking under a microscope? Is this some sort of absorbance assay?

Comment: Check out Steve Boxer's papers on engineering single chain myoglobin in prokaryotes. As I recall it describes blood red colonies.

Comment: @user137,  with naked eye without UV and without microscope. If it's possible ..

Comment: @VGranin Many RFPs have their absorption maxima at around 500nm (green light) and therefore they can fluoresce even under white light. Since red scatters less it is easier to observe too. But the colouration is not very deep. So you can observe redd**ish** colonies.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at [this](http://www.jbc.org/content/275/34/25879.long) paper. They have isolated a chromoprotein similar to GFP, and like the latter it does not have any prosthetic group.

This protein — asFP595 (because it was isolated from the anemone  *Anemonia sulcata.*), is purple coloured under white light and also exhibits a little fluorescent emission in the red region  (λ<sub>max</sub> = 595 nm).

Also have a look at these two papers:

- [GFP-like chromoproteins as a source of far-red fluorescent proteins](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0014579301029301)
- [Major colour patterns of reef-building corals are due to a family of GFP-like proteins](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FPL00006956)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for light-emitting proteins. They gather energy from either absorption of photon (fluorescence) or via random thermal fluctuations. Problem is that fluorescence might be considered forced emission, whereas what you looking for is results of spontaneous transitions. That means that number of photons per second you can expect from latter proteins is $10^4$ times less (I don't have reference for that statement). You need very sensitive detectors and microscopy (sub- or just cellular) is almost impossible at that rate.

You should look into phosphorescence. Also, such thing as GFP-aeqorin might be of interest. That is a calcium-sensistive construct, might give you starting point in searching for reviews.

Another keyword is bioluminescence. See here for more: http://www.olympusconfocal.com/applications/fluorescentproteins.html

Comment: The question clearly specifies "that could be seen without fluorescence"

Comment: phosphorescence is relaxation pathway from states with much longer life-time (ms _versus_ ns for fluorescence). Fluorescence persists after "exciting source has been removed" too, relaxation is just much faster

Comment: @nico Can you elaborate? My guess is that OP wants to see proteins without any harsh excitation light/in complete darkness, and I support OP in that endeavour

Comment: @aandreev the OP says "something like GFP, but that we could see it without UV (not fluorescence)." so giving him information about GFP-related proteins does not really seem a good answer to me... My guess is he's after something like [Bacteriorhodopsin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bacteriorhodopsin) which is purple (albeit I'm not sure it's a good idea to use it as a reporter...)

Comment: @nico are you talking about GFP-aeqorin? it does not require any excitation, you can observe emitted light in complete darkness. Aeqorin is bioluminesce in presence of high Ca concentration, GFP is just a relay here. http://www.pnas.org/content/97/13/7260.fullhttp://www.pnas.org/content/97/13/7260.full

Comment: I was more referring to the link... The way I understand the question he is talking about a chromophore you can see with white light, not in the dark, maybe the OP should clarify...

Comment: @nico, right, in white light. I wrote like chromoproteins, and we can see them in white light. I added this point to the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

GFP-like non-fluorescent chromoproteins are colored and non-fluorescent.
A handful of them - Rtms 5, HcRed, cgCP, gtCP and zFP538 - have reviewed pages on Uniprot.
This paper from Nature describes the use of Rtms 5 to make hair dye: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-019-50283-0

Comment: Whilst true, it's not clear that this answers the question as written, which asks about non-fluorescent proteins found in human cells. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance as to our ways.